# Check if user is logged in with facebook

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

I have a mobile app which communicates with a server.
The mobile user has the opportunity to login:

1. directly from the app
2. by using Facebook

In the first situation, after logging in, I generate a token which is used to authenticate the logged in user.
I want to implement the same with Facebook on the server side.

After searching, I found that accesstoken after the FB login is used for this.
I made a test onto my localhost with my data - facebook login, accesstoken and the https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id&access_token url and FB returns my id.
I logged out and I sent the access token to the URL and FaceBook returned again my id.

I'm expecting a no validation message.
Can you help me on this?

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve. Why do you expect to get message of not valid? Facebook access token has its own validity time. You can read more about Facebook access token [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens)

Comment: So if I want to implement login to my app only with Facebook how can I do that?? I need to secure that after login user in every request is him and after logout out can not requests any more and redirect him to my login page.